# Button will not reach Onclick when nested in table dynamically within updatepanel

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-ajax

I have a page with two panels.
One panel to be filled with two tables consisting of dynamic created buttons.
Both panels are nested within their own respective updatepanels.
My issue is that the buttons i create dynamically refuse to do an onclick.
When i manually add an button like

```
<asp:Button ID="Button2" runat="server" Text="Button" OnClick="Button1_Click" UseSubmitBehavior="false" OnClientClick="false"/>
```

Everything works fine. but not when i create them dynamically with the same variation. Ive included the comments just so people see different approaches i have had without success.

aspx:

```
 <div>
    <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server"></asp:ScriptManager>
    <br />
    <br />
    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanelPhase" UpdateMode="Conditional" runat="server" ChildrenAsTriggers="false">
        <Triggers>
            <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="llNavBtnPhase0" EventName="Click" />
            <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="llNavBtnPhase1" EventName="Click" />
            <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="llNavBtnPhase2" EventName="Click" />
            <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="llNavBtnPhase3" EventName="Click" />
            <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="llNavBtnPhase4" EventName="Click" />
            <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="llNavBtnPhase5" EventName="Click" />
            <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="criticalBtnPhase01" EventName="Click" />
            <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="criticalBtnPhase12" EventName="Click" />
            <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="criticalBtnPhase23" EventName="Click" />
            <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="criticalBtnPhase34" EventName="Click" />
            <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="criticalBtnPhase45" EventName="Click" />

        </Triggers>
        <ContentTemplate>
            <asp:Panel ID="PhasePanel" CssClass="panel col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-xs-2" runat="server" BorderWidth="5px">
                <asp:Panel ID="PhaseMainPanel" runat="server">
                    <asp:Button ID="Button2" runat="server" Text="Button" OnClick="Button1_Click" UseSubmitBehavior="false" OnClientClick="false"/>
                    <asp:Table ID="PhaseMainTable" runat="server"></asp:Table>
                </asp:Panel>
                <asp:Panel ID="PhaseExtraPanel" CssClass="moduleDisplayPanel" runat="server">

                    <asp:Table ID="PhaseExtraTable" class="PhaseBtnPanelAdjustment" runat="server"></asp:Table>
                </asp:Panel>

            </asp:Panel>
        </ContentTemplate>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>

    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanelModule" runat="server" ChildrenAsTriggers="true">

        <ContentTemplate>

            <asp:Panel ID="ContentPanel" CssClass="panel col-lg-8 col-md-8 col-xs-8" runat="server" BorderColor="Green" BorderWidth="5px">
                <asp:Label ID="moduleTitle" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>
                <br />
                <asp:Label ID="moduleArticle" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>
                <br />
                <asp:Image ID="moduelImage" runat="server" />
                <br />
                <asp:LinkButton ID="moduleUrl" runat="server">LinkButton</asp:LinkButton>
                <asp:Button ID="moduleButton" runat="server" Text="Button" Visible="false"/>
            </asp:Panel>
        </ContentTemplate>

    </asp:UpdatePanel>
</div>
```

aspx.cs table with buttons method:
(btw the buttonclass is an extension of aspx:button but with some variable get/set methods included for the content from db)

```
        public void FillFaseTable(Table t, int PID, int lifelineID)
    {

        List<Module> listMod = new List<Module>();
        listMod = DbDataAccessLayer.GetModuleByPhase(PID, lifelineID);
        foreach (var Module in listMod)
        {


            TableRow tRow = new TableRow();
            t.Rows.Add(tRow);
            TableCell tCell = new TableCell();
            LifelineButton btn = new LifelineButton();
            btn.MID = Module.mid;
            btn.moduleID = Module.moduleID;
            btn.title = Module.title;
            btn.Text = Module.title;
            btn.article = Module.article;
            btn.CssClass = "btn btn-primary btn-block moduleBtnConfig";
            btn.Attributes.Add("id", "Button1");

            btn.Attributes.Add("runat", "server");

            btn.Attributes.Add("onclick", "Button1_Click");
            btn.Attributes.Add("UseSubmitBehavior", "false");
            btn.Attributes.Add("OnClientClick", "false");
            //   btn.UseSubmitBehavior = false;
            //   AsyncPostBackTrigger trigger = new AsyncPostBackTrigger();
            //   trigger.ControlID = btn.UniqueID;
            //   trigger.EventName = "Click";
            //   UpdatePanelModule.Triggers.Add(trigger);
            //   btn.Click += new EventHandler(this.sendModuleToPanel_Click);
            //    btn.Attributes.Add("EventName", "Click");
            //   btn.Attributes.Add("Enabled", "true");  
            tCell.Controls.Add(btn);
            tRow.Cells.Add(tCell);
        }
    }
```

aspx.cs button clickevent

```
        void sendModuleToPanel_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        LifelineButton clicked = (LifelineButton)sender;
        moduleTitle.Text = clicked.title;
        moduleArticle.Text = clicked.article;
     //   UpdatePanelModule.Update();
        // title.Text = clicked.title;
        //  article.Text = clicked.article;
    }

    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        moduleTitle.Text = "This works";
        moduleArticle.Text = "this to!";
    }
```

Comment: I never reach the sendModuleToPanel_Click or Button1_Click from my dynamic buttons. All the onclick false stuff was just to prevent from page load refresh. Both btn.click and onclick,button1_Click will not work. Ive tried with breakpoints and the button click never reaches the clickevent method. I created an hidden button just so i could have a trigger in the contentpanel (would not load with reference to an id not yet created.) And the dynamically added trigger would not work.

Comment: you need to add attach an event listener to the created object like this `button.Click += new EventHandler(Button1_Click);` adding attributes is for client side, that means javascript.

Comment: That was my first way to do it, but it didnt work.

Comment: So far i have gathered that most of the issue is that the buttons arent created on pageload. And hence the controller doesnt know about them. The updatepanel does not call for a postback and hence the button created inside it is not part of the "triggering" system for the page. How to tacle this however...?